# Google Maps Implementation Causing Google Page Speed Issues

Tags: php, javascript, performance, google-maps-api-3

I'm a fairly novice webmaster and have received a tremendous amount of help here from the wonderful volunteers and I appreciate all of you.

Recently someone here (Davie) helped me with getting a Google map to query the DB and display on a webpage but it's causing Page Speed issues that I can't seem to crack on my own.

I'll summarize; (links intentionally broken by removing 1 t from https to satisfy algo here)
With this URL:

http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/detail.php?fatherID=37&TypeID=42&ListingID=42

Google Page Speed Says;
(Note From Me: The following urls in full look like:

htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@210000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=36&y=52&z=7&s=&style=api%7Csmartmaps)

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 10 request(s) and 1.9KiB.

```
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?...
```

Additionally, I'm getting;

The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the following resources:

```
htp://www.google.com/.../brand?... 
htps://maps.googleapis.com/.../GeocodeService.Search?... 
htps://maps.googleapis.com/.../StaticMapService.GetMapImage?... 
htps://maps.googleapis.com/.../StaticMapService.GetMapImage?... 
htps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/.../ft?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/.../ft?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/.../ft?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?... 
htps://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?...
```

I'm hoping that someone here is familiar with this and may have an idea on how I could resolve these issues.

This is the code on detail.php

```
$TypeID = isset($_GET['TypeID']) ? $_GET['TypeID'] : ''; 
            $ListingID = isset($_GET['ListingID']) ? $_GET['ListingID'] : ''; 
            $allowed_tables = array('tt_42', 'tt_43');
            $table ="tt_".$TypeID;
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      try {
        if (in_array($table, $allowed_tables)) {
        $query = "SELECT `Address`, `City`, `State/Province`, `Zip/Postal`, `Country` FROM `$table` WHERE `ID` = ? AND `ExpireDate` > NOW()";
        }
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindParam(1,$ListingID);
                $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $stmt->execute();

                $Address = $listing['Address'];
                $City = $listing['City'];
                $State = $listing['State/Province'];
                $Zip = $listing['Zip/Postal'];
                $Country = $listing['Country'];

                echo '<h2>Map of Surrounding Area With Navigational Aides</h2>';
                echo '<div class="CalloutBoxBlue">Hover over map and scroll, or use + and - in LH corner of map to zoom or expand viewing area. Alternatively, hold down mouse to manually move the map to a different geographical location, or drag the person icon to a specific location on the map for a street view.</div>';

                echo '<div id="GoogleMap">'; 
                echo '<iframe scrolling="no" style="width:480px; height:300px; border:0px;" frameborder="0" src="googlemap.php?Address='.$Address.'&amp;City='.$City.'&amp;State='.$State.'&amp;Zip='.$Zip.'&amp;Country='.$Country.'"></iframe>'; 
                echo '</div>'; 
            }

            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error in Displaying Google Map.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
                //file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
             }
```

Additionally, This is the code of googlemap.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map { height: 100% }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
      var geocoder;
      var map;
     <?php
      // Get parameters from URL
      $Address = isset($_GET['Address']) ? $_GET['Address'] : ''; 
      $City = isset($_GET['City']) ? $_GET['City'] : ''; 
      $State = isset($_GET['State']) ? $_GET['State'] : ''; 
      $Zip = isset($_GET['Zip']) ? $_GET['Zip'] : ''; 
      $Country= isset($_GET['Country']) ? $_GET['Country'] : '';

      //Set javascript variables
      echo "var Address ='".$Address."';\n"; 
      echo "var City ='".$City."';\n"; 
      echo "var State ='".$State."';\n";
      echo "var Zip ='".$Zip."';\n"; 
      echo "var Country ='".$Country."';\n";
?>
  function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
      }

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = Address+','+City+','+State+','+Zip+','+Country;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Location not acquired for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload ="initialize()">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if it's really even 100% relevant but I also have the following in my htaccess for caching resources:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

I'm hoping that this is this simplya matter of needing to add a line of code to my htaccess. If so I don't know what I would add and if anyone could help me with this I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Is you map working OK and it's just that Google Page Speed is complaining about the Google resources that the Google Maps API loads? I don't think you can do anything about that. Ignore it.

Comment: I have the same problem. My embedded Google Map works perfectly but PageSpeed told me to "serve a resource from a unique URL, to eliminate duplicate download bytes and additional RTTs.". Yes, I can ignore it, but it is shown as a high priority issue and it's not good from a quality point of view

Answer (score 12):

You can't influence the cache headers of a resource you don't control, these map tiles are on Googles domain, not your's.  I don't know why Google don't follow their own advice when serving the map tiles, but at the end of the day, there's nothing you can do about it other than either remove the map, or try a different mapping solution.

It's just a cache header so won't make the page load any slower on initial loads anyway.  Forget about it and move on.